# How to preppend kendo ui dropdownlist remote data with static item(s)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

May be the title is not as clear as i would like it to be. i've been using kendo ui for a contact management system and i need to prepend the loaded(via ajax) groups for a particular user by say "all Contacts" with value = `-1`. this is an option to delete all contacts which is actually a group but not stated so in the database. so at the point the dropdownlist finishes loading we should have options like (group 1, group 2 ,group 3 loaded from ajax call, all contacts added manually):

```
all contacts
group 1
group 2 
group 3
```

below is my code which works fine, loading the groups for a user.

```
$("#groupCombo").kendoDropDownList({
                placeholder: "all contacts",
                dataTextField: "NAME",
                dataValueField: "GROUP_ID",
                dataSource : {
                    transport:{
                       read: {
                            url: crudServiceBaseUrl+"subscribers/readgroups", 
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                              userId: dataItem.USER_ACCOUNT_ID
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can i achieve that? thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datasource has an inserts function which inserts a new model instance to the datasource.

```
// insert a new model item at the very front of the collection
$("#groupCombo").data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.insert(0, { GROUP_ID: -1, NAME: "all contacts" });
```